# mousemove stops and perfomance problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, mouseevent, mousemove

im trying to make a div move with the mouse (horizontal) like a game heres the code :

```
// Move
setInterval(function () {

     $(document.body).one('mousemove',function(e) {
         $('.p').animate({

             'left': e.pageX

         },300);


     });

 },400);
```

and it works good (with few lag ) but it works 
the problem is if i dont do a thing in the page after 1 min if i try and move the mouse nothing happen 
also theres a delay of 10 sec sometimes

how i can fix this ( get better perfomance)

Comment: You have any demo ? jsfiddle or something

Comment: 1) Don't use `jQuery`. 2) Don't use `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` for animation. ONLY `TRANSFORM`. 3) Don't use `setInerval`/`setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame` better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/molof/pen/MWaLorK)

```js
const mouse = document.querySelector('.mouse');
const mousePos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const lastMousePos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let speedFollow = 0.15;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    mousePos.x = e.pageX;
    mousePos.y = e.pageY;
});
const lerp = (a, b, n) => (1 - n) * a + n * b;

function animateLoop() {
    lastMousePos.x = lerp(
        lastMousePos.x,
        mousePos.x,
        speedFollow
    );
    lastMousePos.y = lerp(
        lastMousePos.y,
        mousePos.y,
        speedFollow
    );

    mouse.style.transform = `translate(${lastMousePos.x}px, ${lastMousePos.y}px)`;
    requestAnimationFrame(animateLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animateLoop);

// other
const inputRange = document.querySelector('input');
const speedFollowBlock = document.querySelector('p b');

inputRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
    speedFollow = this.value;
    speedFollowBlock.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500vh;
}

.mouse {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Speed Follow: <b>0.15</b></p>
<input type="range" min="0.05" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.15">

<div class="mouse"></div>
```